# Twitter Fabric Server Side Authentication

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric

I have develop a mobile app that use [twitter fabric](https://fabric.io) to login with twitter. Fabric gave me user id, user name and two tokens called "authToken" and "authTokenSecret".
I want to verify the user on server side. I can do it easily in facebook with this query: http://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret
([ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=en_US#authClientServer)) In facebook, I used only one token and one url. But in twitter I have two tokens and I have no url. What should I do to verify login on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Twitter's account/verify_credentials endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) to do this. There's [a similar question relating to Digits](https://twittercommunity.com/t/digits-how-can-i-verify-dgtsession-tokens-on-my-own-server/26036) on the Twitter developer community forums which might be helpful.